# Magento2.2.x How to remove a field filter from collection?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, filter

I am loading a collection:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\Demo\Model\Book');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$data = [regionCode => 111,regionCode=>222];
foreach ($data as $address) {
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
            'region', array(
                'eq' => $address['regionCode']
            )
        );
    if($collection->getSize()){ /* ex - 111 region available and 222 is not so both time collection getSize() - 1 */
       $model->setData('region',$address['regionCode']);
       $model->save();
       $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
    }
}
```

How can I remove this (or all) filter from the collection again? I don't want to load a new collection every time the filter changes.

I tried also

```
$collection->resetData();
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effects on the filter.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
protected $bookFactory;
public function __construct(..., Test\Demo\Model\BookFactory $bookFactory, ...) {
    $this->bookFactory = $bookFactory;
}

public function yourFunction() {
    $data = [regionCode => 111,regionCode=>222];
    foreach ($data as $address) {
    $colllection = $this->bookFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $result = $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                    'region', array(
                        'eq' => $address['regionCode']
                    )
                );
        if(count($result)){ /* ex - 111 region available and 222 is not so both time collection getSize() - 1 */
           $model->setData('region',$address['regionCode']);
           $model->save();
           $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
        }
    }
}
```

Try to create singleton, might help you. lets know the result so that we can help more on this.

Comment: Not working above code already tried.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reset conditions then use

`$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);`

It will remove all where condition from Collection.

***You have some logical issue***

*try below solution and see  what Happen*

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\Demo\Model\Book');
$collection = $model->getCollection();
$data = [regionCode => 111, regionCode => 222];

foreach ($data as $address) {
    $cloneCollection = clone $collection;
    $cloneCollection->addFieldToFilter(
            'region', array(
        'eq' => $address['regionCode']
            )
    );
    if ($cloneCollection->getSize()) { /* ex - 111 region available and 222 is not so both time collection getSize() - 1 */
        $model->setData('region', $address['regionCode']);
        $model->save();
        // reset is not required
        //$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
    }
    unset($cloneCollection);
}
```

Comment: I tried but this one is not working. Magento1 in seems like working fine @amit

Comment: after `$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);` add `$collection->load()` and check what happen?

Comment: not working both code dear

Comment: every  stange,please share full code what you have tried

Comment: If you donot want  load collection then you can use `$collection2 = clone $collection` and then use `$collection2->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);` and check what  happen?

Comment: check my updated question dear

Comment: I guess that you have some logic issue on  your  code; What you  have trying to   achieve.

Comment: 111 region available and 222 is not so both time collection getSize()  reutrn 1 insted 222 filter  0